# newpxmath: accents are always bold

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

When using `newpxmath`, the accents in math mode are always bold, regardless of whether the letter underneath is bold or not:

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}

\begin{document}

\centering

$\hat{a}$ $\tilde{a}$ $\bar{a}$ $\check{a}$ $\dot{a}$ $\acute{a}$ $\grave{a}$ $\breve{a}$

\^a \~a \=a \v a \.a \'a \`a \u a

\textbf{\^a \~a \=a \v a \.a \'a \`a \u a}

\end{document}
```

[image: accents with newpx in math mode and text mode]

In the image above, the first line is math mode (medium), the second line is text mode (medium) and the third line is text mode (bold). It can be clearly seen that the accents in math mode are bold.

Is this a bug in `newpxmath` or am I missing something?

---

**Edit:** It seems that the symbol font `npxsy` is corrupt. If you create a font table with

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[scaled=1.042]{zlmtt}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{fonttable}

\begin{document}

\xfonttable{LMS}{npxsy}{m}{n}

\pagebreak

\xfonttable{LMS}{npxsy}{b}{n}

\end{document}
```

you can see that the accents in slots 158–168 look the same in medium and bold weight. The other characters, however, have different medium and bold variants (as it should be).

(There is another unrelated bug: the symbol in slot 11 is mirrored in bold.)

---

**Update: This issue has been fixed since `newpx` version 1.423.**

Comment: Something must have gone wrong in recent times, because an older version shows the expected output.

Comment: The characters are taken from the `pxsys` font. Some time between 2019 and 2020, the font has started to sport boldface accents. I guess an error in assembling the fonts.

Comment: @egreg The accents are taken from the `npxsy` symbol font. But you are right, the font itself is corrupt, I have created font tables and the accents look the same in medium and bold weight. See my updated question.

Comment: @user227621 `npxsy` is a virtual font.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Update 2021-06-02

Version 1.423 (released 2021-05-31) of NewPX fixes the issue. From the README file

> Changes in version 1.423
>
> 1. Corrected weight of regular math accents, which were rendering in bold weight.
> 2. Corrected the bold symbol circledivide in bold weight. (It was inexplicably mirrored.)

The OP's example now produces

[image]

(I've only added a couple of missing accents.)

### Original answer

The characters are taken from the font `pxsys` (via a virtual font). Some time between 2019 and 2020, probably due to an error in assembling the fonts, the accents in `pxsys` have become boldface.

While you wait for a fix, you can redefine the accents to use the `operators` font (which `newpx` tries to avoid for good reasons, but we're in an emergency here).

```
\documentclass{article}
  
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{newpxmath}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\grave}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"12}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\acute}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"13}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\check}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"14}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\breve}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"15}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\bar}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"16}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\mathring}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"17}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\hat}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"5E}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\dot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"5F}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\tilde}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"7E}
\re@DeclareMathAccent{\ddot}{\mathalpha}{operators}{"7F}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\centering

$\hat{a}$ $\tilde{a}$ $\bar{a}$ $\check{a}$ $\dot{a}$ $\acute{a}$
$\grave{a}$ $\breve{a}$ $\ddot{a}$ $\mathring{a}$

\^a \~a \=a \v a \.a \'a \`a \u a \"a \r a

\textbf{\^a \~a \=a \v a \.a \'a \`a \u a \"a \r a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of completeness: I think the `\dddot` accent in slot 168 is also broken, but there is no similar accent in the `operators` font. (This is not a problem for me as I do not need this symbol.) Concerning the `\ddddot` accent in slot 222: It actually looks slightly different in medium and bold, but I'm not sure whether it is correct.

Comment: Have you already notified the package author? If so, you could add that the symbol in slot 11 is also corrupt, it is mirrored in bold.

Comment: @user227621 I'll do ASAP

Comment: Thanks! (No need to rush, the workaround is fine for now.)

Comment: @user227621 Maintainer notified. He's usually quite fast in replying and fixing bugs.

Comment: The fix is now on CTAN (newpx version 1.423). :-)